# Crear Recetas con precios variables en iOS (IAP)

Tags: ios, react-native, pago-in-app

tengo una duda sobre como implementar el In-App-Payment en iOS en mi aplicación de React Native.

En nuestra aplicación, los usuarios pueden crear recetas y ponerles un precio para que otros usuarios las puedan comprar. En el caso de iOS, desde Apple nos obligan a realizar el pago mediante IAP.

Como no se pueden poner precios variables en IAP sino que se tienen que crear diferentes productos con un rango de precios definidos, había pensado en crear en Apple unos diez productos con precios diferentes y que el usuario al crear la receta puediese elegir entre ese tipo de productos.

Mi duda es si esto se puede hacer, y en caso de que se pueda, ¿que tipo de producto de IAP tendría que crear? ¿Consumable o no consumable?

Muchas gracias!

Comment: La pregunta es basada en opiniones. Leyendo la documentación de Apple relacionada con lo pagos, los no consumables serían la opción porque, no puedes comprar varias veces la misma receta verdad?

Comment: Eso es lo que pensaba yo, pero si un usuario quiere poner a la venta una receta por 2.99, por ejemplo, deberá indicar a Apple que está vendiendo el producto de Apple que tenga el precio de 2,99. Si otro usuario cuelga una receta de 2,99 usando el mismo producto, ¿podrá un usuario comprar las 2 recetas si las dos son el mismo producto no consumable, al ser diferentes recetas pero haciendo relación al mismo producto de Apple?